# Is there a tool that tells me if my transfer has been used by others in a ring signature?

Tags: blockchain, ring-signatures, ringsize

Is there a tool that, given a tx hash and/or a specific output, can search through the blockchain to see if it's been used as input in other transfers? This would preferably not be a web service but something I run offline on my own copy of the blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

You can search the blockchain for your outputs with a given address and view key, but I'm not sure if you can actually determine if a given output has been used in other transactions.

Here are some useful tools.

- [lmdbcpp-monero](https://github.com/moneroexamples/lmdbcpp-monero)
- [transactions-export](https://github.com/moneroexamples/transactions-export)